# advice on Linus and Lucy, (Bridge PART)

Tags: chords, melody, tempo

I am currently working on the Vince Guaraldi song, Linus and Lucy; Am having trouble figuring out the bridge of the song, not really sure where to start on it. Any advice

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! To make this answerable, please use the "edit" button to explain more about what kind of trouble you're having. Is reading the sheet music challenging, and you're having trouble filling in by ear? Or you're totally clear on the notes but having practical trouble playing them? Is it a difficulty in fingering, or maybe rhythm? I'm voting to close the question as lacking info, but will happily retract that vote after editing. (Also: Yeah, the bridge is significantly harder than the rest of the song. If it makes you happy, just skip it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment that you should provide more information regarding the trouble you are having but here are some things you should know:

First, this is actually the second bridge at about 1:52, which is really an improvised piano solo. The first bridge, also an improvised solo, starts at about 1:08 and uses the same chords but is played in the original straight 8th Latin feel of the tune. This second bridge is played with a swing feel. If you are unfamiliar with swing feel it has to do with playing eighth notes with more of a triplet feel as indicated in measure 3.

Your confusion might be because of the bass clef. The bass clef actually contains both the upright walking bass part with stems down and the piano left hand with stems up. The bass part is there for reference, it is nearly impossible to play both parts simultaneously. If you want to play the piano part, only play the chords written with stems up. If you want to play the bass part, play the notes with stems down and ignore the chords.

Another approach is to simply improvise your own solo with either or both hands during these sections using the written chord symbols above the treble clef as your guide. It is jazz after all, and in my experience when other pianists play this song they usually improvise over both bridges, not play the exact transcription of Vince’s solo.

Comment: Thank you for the response John I'll work on down stem notes first then see if I can add the top stem with chords later. ill get back you with the results

Comment: @Rage2.0 since you mentioned you are a beginner it would be very difficult for you to play the down stem notes in the bass clef along with the right hand. Focus on the treble clef and gradually try adding the syncopated chords (up stems) in the bass clef when you get comfortable with it.

Comment: then after i get those try adding the down steps is that what your telling me or to forget about down stems and just do the up stems only

Comment: @Rage2.0 Yes, the down stem notes were actually played by the bass player, not the pianist. You can practice them if you like and want to learn about bass lines but what Guaraldi played on the recording is the treble clef in the right hand and the up stem chords of the bass clef in the left hand.

Comment: oh okay thank you then I get it now

Answer (score 0):

considering what I know now
would it be best to...

1. first Learn fingering
2. then learn the swing rhythm
3. then lastly  finish with tempo

is that the best process?

Comment: Consider adding this to your question as an edit instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: This really helps explain what your question was about: looking for how to go about the process of learning the section. (It's not the only way, but it's a pretty good approach for any passage: pitch, then rhythm, then get it up to speed, then worry about expression.) Please still go ahead and edit the question so that it's clear; in theory it "stays open" forever and anyone could add an answer, so it's good to make sure that the question itself contains all the needed info.